# Draw Shape on Top of another Shape in Word doc using C#.net

Tags: c#

I have created 2 shapes `rect1` and `rect2`. I would like to draw `rect2` on top of `rect1`.

```
Shape rect1 = wordDoc.Shapes.AddShape((int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 100, 40, tempRange);

// Put components in that paragraph
rect1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Arun";
rect1.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8;
rect1.ConvertToInlineShape();

Shape rect2 = wordDoc.Shapes.AddShape((int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 50, 20, tempRange);

// Put components in that paragraph
rect2.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "InnerShape";
rect2.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8;
rect2.ConvertToInlineShape();
rect2.ZOrder(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoZOrderCmd.msoBringToFront);

wordDoc.SaveAs(archDocFile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Could you provide us with more information? What is not working currently with your code?

Comment: I would consider adding the two shapes, moving and grouping them, before placing them *inline*. Record macros in Word to help you discover this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the calls to `ConvertToInlineShape()`. Those calls "move" the shapes from the Drawing layer into the Text layer, and that makes them impossible to position freely (they become positioned like characters/words/paragraphs).

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.converttoinlineshape

To position the now floating shapes, set the properties [Top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.top) and [Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.left) (or perhaps [TopRelative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.toprelative) and [LeftRelative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.leftrelative)). Read the docs to see how these work!

Comment: Hi Peter,
Thank you very much for Your support.
Its working. Second shape is coming on top of first shape. But the issue is both shapes not coming in the exact Range. Its drawing on top of the page.